# Convert google cloud storage file to base64 string

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, base64, google-cloud-storage, sendgrid

i am retrieving  a pdf file from google cloud storage. I need to convert this file to base64 string so that i can pass to api as request.This is is nodejs

```
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");
const storage = new Storage(options);
const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);   
let remoteFile = bucket.file(fileName);
```

Need to convert this remoteFile object to base64 string.
Actually i need to pass this remoteFile as attachment to sendgrid mail api.

Comment: I'm trying to do the exact same thing but I can't get it to work. I'm trying to download a pdf from a google cloud bucket and attach it to a mail using sendgrid. Did you solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can find here in the [library sample](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#download-examples), you need to download the file content first, and then you can do what you want with, encoded it in base64 if you want

```
....

remoteFile.download().then(function(data) {
  const file = data[0];
  ... convert base64 and continue here....
});
```